# Regex to match NGinx log file

Tags: regex, linux

I'm trying to write a regex to detect log entries in NGinx.

Below is a list of entries that should match the expression:

```
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaa3 HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 34489 5 0.073
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaa1 HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 33339 5 0.091
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaa4 HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 21907 5 0.076
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaab HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 19671 5 0.159
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaa2 HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 15359 5 0.104
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaa5 HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 35095 5 0.084
```

Below is a list of entries that should not match the expression:

```
1.1.1.1 - - [28/Mar/2019:13:58:55 +0000] "GET /pro/p/id/63aaaaaaaaa8/4.4.4.4/YL0000000000.rom HTTP/1.1" "-" "Yealink W52P 25.81.0.10 00:15:aa:aa:aa:f9" 404 - 1 5 0.137
2.2.2.2 - - [28/Mar/2019:13:58:56 +0000] "GET /pro/p/id/67aaaaaaaaa0/4.4.4.4/T46G.rom HTTP/1.1" "-" "Yealink SIP-T46G 28.81.0.20 00:15:aa:aa:aa:eb" 404 - 1 5 0.128
3.3.3.3 - - [28/Mar/2019:13:59:00 +0000] "GET /pro/p/id/67aaaaaaa750/4.4.4.4/T46G.rom HTTP/1.1" "-" "Yealink SIP-T46G 28.81.0.20 00:15:aa:aa:aa:eb" 404 - 1 5 0.131
```

I am trying to exclude lines that contain one of a number of strings: Polycom, Yealink, Snom.

My current regex is as follows:

`^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+) - - \[\d{2}\/\w{3}\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \+\d{4}\] \"GET \/pro\/p((?!Polycom|Snom|Yealink).).+(?:403|404)`

EDIT: added an additional requirement to this regex - need to also match the 403/404 status of these lines

However this does not work correctly and gives false positives.

Answer (score 1):

try Regex: `(?!.*(Polycom|Snom|Yealink))^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+) - - \[(\d{2})\/\w{3}\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \+\d{4}\] \"GET \/pro\/p`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GXpgl3/2)

Comment: I should have been clearer in my original post - I need to match the other bits in my regex too as it will stop false positives

Comment: I also need to capture the IP

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl solution

```
perl -ne ' /^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+) - - \[(\d{2})\/\w{3}\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \+\d{4}\] \"GET \/pro\/p(?!.*(Polycom|Snom|Yealink))/ms and print ' file
```

with the below inputs

```
$ cat btong.log
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaa3 HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 34489 5 0.073
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaa1 HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 33339 5 0.091
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaa4 HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 21907 5 0.076
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaab HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 19671 5 0.159
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaa2 HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 15359 5 0.104
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaa5 HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 35095 5 0.084
1.1.1.1 - - [28/Mar/2019:13:58:55 +0000] "GET /pro/p/id/63aaaaaaaaa8/4.4.4.4/YL0000000000.rom HTTP/1.1" "-" "Yealink W52P 25.81.0.10 00:15:aa:aa:aa:f9" 404 - 1 5 0.137
2.2.2.2 - - [28/Mar/2019:13:58:56 +0000] "GET /pro/p/id/67aaaaaaaaa0/4.4.4.4/T46G.rom HTTP/1.1" "-" "Yealink SIP-T46G 28.81.0.20 00:15:aa:aa:aa:eb" 404 - 1 5 0.128
3.3.3.3 - - [28/Mar/2019:13:59:00 +0000] "GET /pro/p/id/67aaaaaaa750/4.4.4.4/T46G.rom HTTP/1.1" "-" "Yealink SIP-T46G 28.81.0.20 00:15:aa:aa:aa:eb" 404 - 1 5 0.131

$ perl -ne ' /^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+) - - \[(\d{2})\/\w{3}\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \+\d{4}\] \"GET \/pro\/p(?!.*(Polycom|Snom|Yealink))/ms and print ' btong.log
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaa3 HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 34489 5 0.073
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaa1 HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 33339 5 0.091
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaa4 HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 21907 5 0.076
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaab HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 19671 5 0.159
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaa2 HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 15359 5 0.104
7.7.7.7 - - [28/Mar/2019:03:30:06 +0000] "GET /pro/p/001565a2aaa5 HTTP/1.1" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0" 404 - 35095 5 0.084

$
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use regex as this is going to be used in fail2ban in the `failregex` directive

Comment: However presumably I can transfer the regex logic?

Comment: I just noticed that I omitted something from the original request - I need to match the 403/404 status in the log - how would I add this?

Comment: looks like you are changing the question now.. could you please update it